# Can't add attribute to object JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, attributes

I'm recovering an object from mongoose, I can see and access all it's attributes, but I can't create new attributes for that object.

What I tried

```
transfer.test= 'test';
```

Order of calls:

```
  console.log(transfer);
  transfer.test = 'test';
  console.log(transfer);
  console.log(transfer.test);
```

Output:

```
{ _id: '0000000000000303',
  Ammount: '1',
  State: 'SUCCESS',
  TimeStampStarted: '1512043753',
  LastUpdate: '1512043763',
  __v: 0 }
{ _id: '0000000000000303',
  Ammount: '1',
  State: 'SUCCESS',
  TimeStampStarted: '1512043753',
  LastUpdate: '1512043763',
  __v: 0 }
test
```

Why isn't it there? why am I not getting some error, warning etc?

PD I checked the type of transfer, it's an object

Comment: what is the value of `Object.keys(transfer).indexOf("test")` ? if it is `-1`, then `test` is an inherited property.

Comment: Show us the full code please. Are you sure that `transfer` is the object that you are showing ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 it's a 2

Comment: Are you later on removing this property? Since console.log's output is often evaluated when user tries to expand the output later.

Comment: @Weedoze There are no other transfer objects in my code, only there and I'm editing and printing the same object: console.log(transfer); console.log(transfer.test);

Comment: @gurvinder372 I don't delete anything related to that object

Comment: @EnriqueAlcazar Is is possible for you to replicate this issue in a fiddle or a snippet?

Comment: @gurvinder372 https://jsfiddle.net/mL5agd3e/ It's weird, now both prints include the new property including the print done before creating the new property

Comment: @EnriqueAlcazar That is because console.log's output is evaluated when user tries to expand the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see when console.log a Mongoose object is not all its info, just a representation. Mongoose objects have a lot of variables that Mongoose needs to manage it. Sometimes, this represantion is not updated. Although it is storing the information correctly in the object, it is not printing it well. If you don't need Mongoose characteristics in this object anymore, you can do

```
transfer = transfer.toObject();
```

and it will be a JavaScript object from now on, and it should show everything updated.